# Accessing Virtual Server Running inside Hyper-V

Tags: server, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v, virtual-network

I have created a Linux server inside Hyper-V. Normally If we have IP of server then we can browse pages being severed. But How to do that in case of Hyper-V VM. 
Basically i am unable to reach server using the IP because it is Virtual.

I have creating network switch but it didn't help. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In Hyper-V manager there is a networking tab at bottom which shows IP of the machine if it is running.